# Cannot resolve conflicts(application is locking files)

Tags: git, conflict, atlassian-sourcetree

I am trying to pull from another branch into mine, and I get merge errors. When I try to resolve them, I get this error from SourceTree: "Could not update one or more files, please check that no other application is locking your files". But I am sure there is no other application using my file, any idea how to fix?

Comment: https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Bitbucket-questions/Could-not-update-one-or-more-files/qaq-p/602194

Comment: ..it seems like this happened with the "theirs" change being a delete, so "resolving using theirs" should delete the file. I worked around it by marking the files as resolved then deleting them manually.

Comment: I also see this issue when the "mine" change is a delete, so "resolving using mine" should delete the file.  See https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-2366

Answer (score 17):

If you've already checked your .git/index.lock file, then you are likely seeing a SourceTree bug.  See jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREEWIN-2366

The bug occurs when either the "Mine" change or the "Theirs" change is a file deletion.  Trying to "Resolve using 'Mine'" or "Resolve using 'Theirs'" (respectively), which should result in a file deletion, will give you this error instead.

One **workaround** (on Windows) is to select the all the conflicted files you want to resolve this way, right click, and select "Remove".  The files will (strangely) not change status or disappear, but should remain selected.  Right click again, and select "Mark as resolved".  This will delete them correctly and resolve the conflict.

Comment: works great. Never had this issue before